# Excel, cannot connect to XMLA Webservice

Tags: excel, database, connection, xmla

I try to create connection to a XMLA Web Service in Excel. I'm using Analysis Services connection assistant. I fill the first mask with web service url and credentials. Then I get 10 DISCOVER_PROPERTIES and one DISCOVER_SCHEMA_ROWSETS requests on server. After last DISCOVER_SCHEMA_ROWSETS I get a notification (no error dialog) in excel, that the data connection assistant can't find the database list in the given data source. Where I can get further information to the occured error? I'm grateful for any help!

DISCOVER_SCHEMA_ROWSETS MESSAGE:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Session xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis" SessionId="D5C7494A-14DC-47F4-B9A5-AC6A487BCC38"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
      <RequestType>DISCOVER_SCHEMA_ROWSETS</RequestType>
      <Restrictions>
        <RestrictionList/>
      </Restrictions>
      <Properties>
        <PropertyList>
          <LocaleIdentifier>1031</LocaleIdentifier>
        </PropertyList>
      </Properties>
    </Discover>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and DiscoverResponse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <DiscoverResponse xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
      <return>
        <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
          <xsd:schema xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xsd:element name="root">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xsd:element name="row" type="row"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:complexType name="row">
              <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element name="SchemaName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" sql:field="SchemaName"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:schema>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DISCOVER_DATASOURCES</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DISCOVER_PROPERTIES</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DISCOVER_SCHEMA_ROWSETS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DISCOVER_ENUMERATORS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DISCOVER_KEYWORDS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DISCOVER_LITERALS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_CUBES</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_DIMENSIONS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_MEASURES</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_HIERARCHIES</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_LEVELS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_MEMBERS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_PROPERTIES</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DBSCHEMA_COLUMNS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DBSCHEMA_PROVIDER_TYPES</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DBSCHEMA_TABLES</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>DBSCHEMA_TABLES_INFO</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_ACTIONS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_FUNCTIONS</SchemaName>
          </row>
          <row>
            <SchemaName>MDSCHEMA_SETS</SchemaName>
          </row>
        </root>
      </return>
    </DiscoverResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

First test by putting the URL of webservice in your browser and see if its working.

You can download [Microsoft Office XP Web Services Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140268%28v=office.10%29.aspx) which provide an addin in VBA interface. The addin allows you to specify a path for webservice and creates classes for you. You can use this class and call the functions in your webservice.

Comment: excel invokes my web service. If I debug it, I see the messages. You mean I should invoke my web service with vba? The web service is a java servlet.